# Retrieving build logs from jenkins in real-time using java client

Tags: java, jenkins, file-io

For some task, I need to get build logs from jenkins in real time. I am using the following code to retrieve logs. However the problem with this is, since I am running the below code in real time (when the jenkins job is running), i get partial data since the build logs keep updating as the job progresses. For example, let's say the job started at 12 PM and lasts for 10 min, when the below code runs at 12:01 PM it would get only partial logs since the logs would keep on appending as the job progresses.

Is there an effective way to keep polling and get all the delta for each request.

Thanks.

```
public static InputStream getInputStream(){

        URL urls = null;
        try {
            urls = new URL("https://jenkins-prod/job/Tests/job/Pipeline_Tests/lastBuild/consoleText");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (connection.getInputStream())));

              String line;
              do {
                  line = br.readLine();
                  System.out.println(line);
                  System.out.flush();
              } while  ((line = br.readLine())!= null);

            return connection.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Removed [tag:apache-kafka], unless I missed something

Comment: In general, I would suggest you setup slf4j to send data to a file or to syslog, then you can forward data from there

Answer (score 0):

If requirement is really to read build logs via program on real-time(while build is running); Let's assume you will read logs of job "A"

- Define pre-build action on job "A" that will start your "listener"
  program before build starts.
- Pre-build will start your listener, then you will catch the time when build starts, if  you can listen in small periods.

But, if requirement can differ in a way that you can have the content after builds are finished, you can use such plugins to send build-log content to any place. One example https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin plugin to send e-mails.